# Printing nth bell number

Tags: python, combinatorics

[Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) \$B(n)\$ is defined as the number of ways of splitting \$n\$ into any number of parts, also defined as the sum of previous \$n\$ [Stirling numbers of second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Here is a snippet of Python code that Wikipedia provides (slightly modified) to print bell numbers:

```
def bell_numbers(start, stop):

   t = [[1]]                        ## Initialize the triangle as a two-dimensional array
   c = 1                            ## Bell numbers count
   while c <= stop:
       if c >= start:
           yield t[-1][0]           ## Yield the Bell number of the previous row
       row = [t[-1][-1]]            ## Initialize a new row
       for b in t[-1]:
        row.append(row[-1] + b)  ## Populate the new row
       c += 1                       ## We have found another Bell number
       t.append(row)                ## Append the row to the triangle
   for b in bell_numbers(1, 9):
       print b
```

But I have to print the \$n\$th bell number, so what I did was I changed the second last line of code as follows:

```
for b in bell_numbers(n,n)
```

This does the job, but I was wondering of an even better way to print the \$n\$th bell number.

Comment: Please check whether your code is indented correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Dobinski](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DobinskisFormula.html) formula for calculating Bell numbers more efficiently.

Dobinski's formula is basically something like this line, although the actual implementation is a bit more complicated (this function neither returns precise value nor is efficient, see this [blogpost](http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009/03/computing-generalized-bell-numbers.html) for more on this):

```
import math
ITERATIONS = 1000
def bell_number(N):
    return (1/math.e) * sum([(k**N)/(math.factorial(k)) for k in range(ITERATIONS)])
```

E.g. you can use the [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) package to calculate the nth Bell number using this formula:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 30
print bell(100)
```

You can check the implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/source/browse/trunk/mpmath/functions/functions.py)

Comment: The first method is returning error values as follows, the 5th bell number is actually 52 but this returns 50.767... and same is for other higher bell polynomials as well, I dont understand why this error is showing up.

Comment: I know my `bell_number` function doesn't return precise value, it is just meant to display the general idea. The reason for the error is described in the referred [blogpost](http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009/03/computing-generalized-bell-numbers.html), look for [this part](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/f/e/2fe8b4e5768cc4c3b2884cab699317c0.png)

Comment: I see, thanks for this awesome answer, but i cant fully understand what mpmaths is, is it a pyhton library? and how to write the code that uses mpmaths in calculating Bell number,that code returns an error.

Comment: mpmath is a Python module (library). You'll need to install that before you can use it. [mpmath install instructions](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/setup.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change `yield t[-1][0]` to `yield t[-1][-1]` so the \$n\$th Bell number is on the \$n\$th line - that is, gives correct output, so the call:

```
for b in bell_numbers(1, 9):
    print b
```

prints the correct bell numbers 1 to 9.

So, if you just want the \$n\$th Bell number only:

```
for b in bell_numbers(n, n):
    print b
```

or change the code to take just one argument.